# Inserting Accounts and Contacts (that look up to the Account) in the same class

Tags: apex, account, contact, insert

I'm trying to insert Accounts and Contacts in the same class. I'm inserting the account first, then inserting contacts, based on the account name.

The account field in contacts is not getting populated. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

First I insert accounts, then contacts using:

`insert DTC_Accs;
insert DTC_Contact;`

Accounts are inserted by reading a csv:

```
public List<Account> createAccs(String[] filelines) {
    List<Account> Accs = new List<Account>();
    for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
    {
        String[] inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');


        Account temp = new Account();
        temp.Industry = inputValues[0];
        temp.Name = inputValues[1];
        // Add the Account to the list
        Accs.add(temp);
    }

    return Accs;
}`
```

Contacts are inserted with:

```
    public List<Contact> createContact(String[] filelinesContact) {        List<Contact> Conts = new List<Contact>();
    for (Integer j=1;j<filelinesContact.size();j++)
    {
        String[] inputvaluesContact = filelinesContact[j].split(',');


        //set the value of the contact 
        Contact tempContact = new Contact();
        tempContact.Salutation = inputvaluesContact[1];
        tempContact.FirstName = inputvaluesContact[2];
        tempContact.LastName = inputvaluesContact[3];
        tempContact.Phone = inputvaluesContact[4];
        tempContact.MobilePhone = inputvaluesContact[5];
        tempContact.Email = inputvaluesContact[6];
        tempContact.AccountID = objectIdbyName.get('Account').get(inputValuesContact[7]);
        // Add the Contact to the list
        Conts.add(tempContact);
    }

    return Conts;
}`
```

The code that sets the account on contacts is in another class and is:

```
        objectIdbyName.put('Account', new map<string, id>());
    for(Account a : [Select id, Name from Account])
        objectIdbyName.get('Account').put(a.Name,a.Id);
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you will need to include some code to see where you went wrong. Please **[edit]** your question, or it is likely to be closed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'inserting the contacts based on the account name'? Can you provide a code sample of what you have tried? On Contacts you can set the AccountId field, have you tried that?

Comment: @sfdcfox edited!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert the same contact as Account

Let's suppose we have to insert 5 Accounts and with Account Name, we have to insert 5 respective Contacts.

```java
list<Account> acclist = new list<Account>();

for(integer i=1; i<5; i++){
    Account objacc = new Account(Name = 'Manish Bikuniya' + i);
    acclist.add(objacc);
}

insert acclist;

list<Contact> conlist = new list<Contact>();

for(Account objacc :acclist){
    Contact objcontact = new Contact();
    objcontact.AccountId = objacc.id;
    objcontact.LastName = objacc.Name;
    conlist.add(objcontact);
}

insert conlist;
```

Comment: try/catch with an empty catch block (or one that just writes to the debug log) is bad practice, so I've removed it from your example code (along with doing proper indentation). Using `Database.insert(sobjectList, false);` would be a better approach if you need to detect/process failures. Also strange that you use the SObject constructor to set the Account field, but not for the Contact fields.